# Why is my ContentProvider unknown?

Tags: android, cursor, uri, android-manifest, android-contentprovider

AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <!-- Provides search suggestions for addresses -->
 <provider android:name="com.my.app.provider.SearchAddressProvider"
              android:authorities="com.my.app.provider.SearchAddressProvider" />
```

the `<manifest ... >` section

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.my.app" android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">
```

From my provider class `SearchAddressProvider`

```
 public static final String KEY_ADDRESS_1 = SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1;
 public static final String KEY_ADDRESS_2 = SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_2;
 public static final String KEY_MARKER = SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_ICON_1;
 public static final String KEY_FAVORITE = SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_ICON_2;

 private static String AUTHORITY = "com.my.app.provider.SearchAddressProvider";
 public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY
        + "/searchaddress");
 private static final UriMatcher uriMatcher = buildUriMatcher();

 ....

 @Override
public String getType(Uri uri) {
    switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
    case SEARCH_WORDS:
        return WORDS_MIME_TYPE;
    case GET_WORD:
        return DEFINITION_MIME_TYPE;
    case SEARCH_SUGGEST:
        return SearchManager.SUGGEST_MIME_TYPE;
    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URL " + uri);
    }
}
```

yet in my activity that calls this class with those definitions, with this command:

```
 Cursor cursor = managedQuery(SearchAddressProvider.CONTENT_URI, null, null, new String[] {query}, null);
```

I get `IllegalArgumentException Unknown URI`

thats a problem for me, solution?

Comment: Please post the code of your provider. Specifically its `getType(Uri uri)` where it decides whether it can serve the uri.

Comment: Also post `<manifest ..>` section of your AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: Arhimed, I've posted it, you might be on to something. I am trying to get map address data, not words (I copied this from the SearchableDictionary example), how would I fix this to parse map data URI?

Comment: Your manifest looks Ok. It sounds like you didn't implement the ContentProvider methods. If yes, then follow the sample for details implementation - http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/resources/samples/SearchableDictionary/src/com/example/android/searchabledict/DictionaryProvider.html

Comment: can you look at this? this is my entire ContentProvider, I'm not sure which parts I actually need to add or change. I am doing address lookups , can you assist? http://pastebin.com/vwV3pLph

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code:

```
public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY
                    + "/searchaddress");

/**
 * Builds up a UriMatcher for search suggestion and shortcut refresh
 * queries.
 */
private static UriMatcher buildUriMatcher() {
    UriMatcher matcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    // to get definitions...
    matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "dictionary", SEARCH_WORDS);
    matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "dictionary/#", GET_WORD);
    // to get suggestions...
    matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_QUERY,
                    SEARCH_SUGGEST);
    matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_QUERY + "/*",
                    SEARCH_SUGGEST);

    return matcher;
}
```

Note, your `UriMatcher` does not support `searchaddress`, it deals with `dictionary` instead. So I think the `CONTENT_URI` should be changed to:

```
public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + 
         "/dictionary");
```

Comment: Arhimed, what method DOES support searchaddress? that is what I want it to support, NOT DICTIONARIES. How do I correct it specifically for addresses. I have a hunch, but nothing solid yet

Comment: Then change the code of `buildUriMatcher()` - instead of `"dictionary"` and `"dictionary/#"` use `"searchaddress"` and `"searchaddress/#"`. So then `getType()` will return either `DEFINITION_MIME_TYPE` or `WORDS_MIME_TYPE` instead of throwing the `IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URL " + uri)`.